# Limit of a function as x tends to infinity using epsilon definition

Tags: limits

i got a question to prove the limit of (5x+2)/(3x-5) as x tends to infinity is 5/3 using epsilon definition. I'm struck at the step to find epsilon.

Comment: You don't "find" $\varepsilon$ in standard proofs. You are given an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, and the is something else you have to find (usually a $\delta$ or an $N$). Read an example of two and see if you can spot this. If you are trying to find it, then you haven't yet understood how those definitions and proofs work.

Comment: That makes even less sense. Could you post the exact problem statement in your question? (Possibly translated as faithfully as you can, if it's not in English.)

Comment: It says "using the definition only prove the following". In the lecture the lecturere did an example on these type of questions and he asked to write x as a function of epsilon(sorry for the misunderstanding). For an example x>(3/epsilon)

Comment: That makes more sense. In that example, $x$ isn't a function of $\varepsilon$. What is a function of epsilon is that bound $N=\frac 3\varepsilon$, and then we show that as long as $x>N$, the value of the fraction is closer than $\varepsilon$ to the limit value. That's the definition of a limit at $\infty$. For your fraction you presumably need a different bound than $\frac3\varepsilon$, but otherwise it should be the same.